# starship shaped like a manta ray encounters doomsday machine from Magellanic cloud piloted by a lady with cat’s eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship

It was published in the '70s, but I can’t remember the name of it. The manta ship docks with the doomsday ship, and the girl is in hibernation, she is extracted, then ... they try and stop the doomsday ship.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: What does "doomsday machine" signify in the story? Is it supposed to destroy the whole cosmos, or the Milky Way galaxy, or is it just supposed to sterilize planet earth like the Russian doomsday machine in the Dr.Strangelove movie?

Comment: It's revenge against the original Terran home worlds. The folks over in the Cloud were not nice... feeling victimized by their mutations for some reason, can't remember.